# Can't access the data in AsyncStorage inside the function

Tags: javascript, react-native

Now i created an async function getUsers which returns a promise with the correct data. Then, I tried retrieving the data in a form of array by using .then(). However, the data is empty when I call getUsers() in get().

```
getUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@FriendBook:Users");
    if (users !== null) {
      return JSON.parse(users);
    }
    return [];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Unable to load users", error);
  }
};

get = () => {
  var p = getUsers();
  var users = [];

  p.then((res) => {
    users = res;
  });

  return users;
};
```

Comment: If AsyncStorage is an asynchronous function you can’t return users like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @evolutionxbox well, I already tried using async function and awaiting the response but still no luck

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. Remember I can’t see you screen or the code you’ve used.